# HTTP Get Request - Program Stops

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I'm developing a javaME project in which I'm reading a variable from a device and updating it in a Website. Basically, in Eclipse, the app runs perfectly. But when running from my java modem(code runs much faster) it gets stuck after running for one hour. I have done some tests and the program stops at the line in which I try to get the response code. So, am I building the method incorrectly? Should I make anything different?

```
  void enviarPost(int i, String comando)throws IOException, IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException, ATCommandFailedException{     

        System.out.println("Connecting to websitedummy.com...");
            if(i == 1)
            {
            url = "http://websitedummy.com/index.php?IMEI=" + imeiX + "&IP=" + ipX;
            }
            //53543D303B44723D4E616F
            else
            {
            System.out.println("Atribuir url2");
            url2 = comando;             
            url = "http://websitedummy.com/index.php?data={\"IMEI\":\""+imeiX+"\",\"TS\":\"20/04/13-08:31:44\",\"SER\":\""+url2+"\"}";               

            System.out.println("Atribuiu: "+ url2);
            }



            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Done1");
                connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
                System.out.println("Done2");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
                System.out.println("Done3");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
                System.out.println("Done4");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                System.out.println("Done5");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                int con = connection.getResponseCode();
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println(con);
                if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    System.out.println("Vamos6");
                    inputstream_ = connection.openInputStream();
                    int ch;
                    while ((ch = inputstream_.read()) != -1 ) {
                        dataReceived.append((char) ch);

                    }
                    System.out.println("Updated");
                    acabouatualizar=1;
                    connection.close();
                    System.out.println("Closed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    // Connection not ok
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e);

            } finally {
                if (inputstream_ != null) {
                    try {

                        inputstream_.close();

                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        System.out.println( e1);
                    }
                }
                if (connection == null) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Connection closed");
                        connection.close();

                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        System.out.println(e2);
                    }
                }
            }
            }
```

The program stops and doesn't present any type of exception which makes me think it only freezes. The last output I can see is "Done5".

Edit: Made the modem reset at every hour. Avoided the problem, not resolved it. 
Anyone? :)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Made the modem to reset at each hour so the problem is avoided. Still not solved. Anyone?

Comment: What are these `Connector` and `HttpConnection` classes? And what does [tag:HttpURLConnection] have to do with it?

Comment: They are part of the javax library. I'm of limited in terms of solutions due to the solution being in javaME. It only allows me to work with solutions until 1.3IDE.
Connector:
http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/cdc1.1.2/jsr218/javax/microedition/io/package-summary.html 
HttpConnection
http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was caused by this line

```
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

Removed it and runs like a charm. 
Solved.

Answer (score 1):

To help with the debug and for you to be able to know if the problem is the connection never actually closing, try to set a timeout for the connection:

```
con.setConnectTimeout(5000); //set timeout to 5 seconds
```

directly after the setRequestProperty();

It might solve the freezing.

Comment: Going to try it. I'll post the results as soon as I get them. Thanks

Comment: Nope. The method setConnectTimeout is part of httpUrlConnection which is 1.7IDE.

Can't do it like that :(